# Voice control script that works offline (localhost with no internet connection)

Tags: javascript, controls, localhost, offline, voice

I'm looking for a voice control script for my website (it's like an app) working offline running on localhost with no internet access. I used talater.com/annyang, it super simple to use and works perfectly, but needs internet access to work. My question is: Do you know any voice control scripts that I can use offline (localhost, no internet access)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this isn't the right place for such a question. Secondly, it's already been asked here: [Software Recommendations/StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34599/offline-javascript-speech-recognition-library)

There they suggested [PocketSphinx JS](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js). Also, some browsers now have a [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) which you could implement or if you have Node.js at your disposal then there's a number of speech recognition packages (first brief npm search gave me this one: [Speech Tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speech-tree)).

Comment: Alrighty, thanks, that helps a lot! Sorry about posting it in wrong place then.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help

Comment: This uses web speech API which uses Google cloud and hence it's not an offline solution

Comment: @bluejayke you picked the 1 non-offline proposal out of many, good job. I also mentioned Speech Tree and suggested to look up Node-specific packages on `npm`.

Comment: Speech tree is what I was talking about, it uses the web speech API behind the scenes